# Local.ERROR: Call to a member function all() on array

Tags: php, laravel

I'm yet to understand what needed to be fixed in the code making it generate the error. What is to be put right?

This is the code:

```
public function addmember()
{
    try {
          $data = Input::all();

        $validator = Validator::make($data->all(),[
           'firstname'=>'required|min:2|max:20',
           'lastname'=>'required|min:2|max:20',
           'email'=>'required|email',
           'password'=>'required|min:6',
           'mobile_no'=>'required|numeric|min:10|max:10',
           'dob'=>'required|date'
          ]);
          if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()]);
          }
          else{
          $firstName = $data['firstname'];
          $lastName = $data['lastname'];
          $email = $data['email'];
          $password = $data['password'];
          $mobile_number = $data['mobile_no'];
          $dob = $data['dob'];
          $query = "call insert_data_of_member_by_admin('$firstName','$lastName','$email','$password','$mobile_number','$dob');";
          $result= DB::select($query);
          return Response::json($result,200);
        }
   } catch (Exception $e) {

   }
}
```

Comment: the 4th line of that method where you are calling `all()` on an array .. should have a stack trace that tells you the exact line somewhere

Comment: `$data` is an array so no need for `->all()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `all()` isn't an array method what will generate an error, so try to remove it from :

```
$validator = Validator::make($data->all(),[
__________________________________^^^^^^^
```

`$data` is already an array.